# Missing .angular-cli.json file: Angular

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I've created Angular2 project using Angular-cli with the following command:

```
ng new project-name
```

but, I don't see `.angular-cli.json` file in my root folder of the project. The angular-cli version I'm using is 1.0.2. I've created multiple projects with cli in the past and have never encountered this problem. Is it because of the recent update? If yes, where can I find the json file? Or do I need to create it manually?

Comment: what happens if you try to run `locate angular-cli.json`?

Comment: "Don't see" in what sense? What happens when you run `ng serve`?

Comment: @torazaburo ng serve works fine! I'm able to use all the cli commands, but can't locate the angular-cli.json file in the root directory.
I did 'locate angular-cli.json' and got the following path:
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/blueprints/ng/files/angular-cli.json

Comment: Files starting with a dot are hidden files on Unix-like systems. execute `ls -a` in the root folder, and you'll see it.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

**Update:** With **Angular 6.0.0** the **filename is changed** from .angular-cli.json to **angular.json.**

.angular-cli.json is a hidden file since @angular/cli version 1.0.

The file got the prefix `.` with this version 1.0 , so it is hidden as @JB Nizet commented.

The change is described in the wiki of @angular/cli [stories 1.0 update](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update)

The location of this file is unchanged.

When you create a new project with @angular/cli 1.0.2, the message

`create .angular-cli.json`

is displayed.

Comment: But how can I run the project developed in previous versions via latest angular-cli ??

Comment: please  see https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4 with https://update.angular.io/ Update Guide

Comment: I tried to rename my angular-cli.json with angular.json it didnt work for me.. it is throwing and error in the same package. PS : I have migrated my application from angular 5 to angular 6.. afte Migration i am getting error as "Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found"

Answer (score 44):

**`angular-cli.json` file has been renamed/replaced to `angular.json` from version 6.0.**

[mentioned here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/releases)

Comment: this is important to know for everybody who can not find it! thanks

Comment: I tried to rename my angular-cli.json with angular.json it didnt work for me.. it is throwing and error in the same package.

PS : I have migrated my application from angular 5 to angular 6.. afte Migration i am getting error as "Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found"

Answer (score 2):

I also somehow created an angular project that didn't have a .angular-cli/json file, but that otherwise appeared to build and test successfully.

Turns out that I created it by cloning the quickstart from GitHub using the instructions here: https://angular.io/guide/setup

If you install the full CLI, then it will generate projects that contain the missing file.  Use `npm install -g @angular/cli`, per https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

Answer (score 2):

You will not see   angular-cli.json instead you see this (with dot at the beginning) .angular-cli.json
which is hidden file. On finder MAC OS go to the project root folder and do

```
command + shift + .
```

or on eclipse
open the project in navigator

`Window->Show View->Navigator`

and

`Eclipse -> Preferences -> Remote Systems -> Files`: Check the `"Show hidden files" Ok.`

That way you could display or hide hidden file like (`.git, .gitIgnore`)

Comment: What is "angular-cli.json is .angular-cli.json" ??

Comment: File name is indicated as hidden. Actually i need to update the discription.

Answer (score 1):

`angular-cli.json` has now been changed to `angular.json` on angular 6

Answer (score 0):

Click on ‘View Menu’ in the Project Explorer view and select ‘Filter(sts) / Customize View(eclipse)’. Uncheck the .*resources filter and you will now be able to see the .angular-cli.json in the project structure.