# how can we use environment variable in angular version >=2

Tags: angular

I am now reading the angular4 doc, and noticed, there is one folder, environments, and under which, there are multiple environment files, such as environment.ts, environment.prod.ts, if we build using env=prod, then prod environments variable will be used.
Now I have one question, how can I get environment variable from the code? I googled the doc quite a lot and there is no mention about this.
Can anyone help to tell me how to obtain environment variable values?
Thanks

Comment: The pertinent solution is to use environment variables that we can retrieve from an external source, https://smaillns.medium.com/handling-environment-variables-in-angular-application-125083e905f6?sk=8277e6be4830431fb2d7f8f1ca74069d

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> If you are using CLI then in `.angular-cli.json` file, place this code.
>   (From angular 6 onward, `.angular-cli.json` file is renamed to `.angular.json`)

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
```

In dev environment  file, you can write

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
url: 'http://something.com'
};
```

And in prod  environment  file, you can write

```
export const environment = {
production: true,
url: 'http://something.com'
}
```

In components or services, you can use like

```
import {environment} from '../../environments/environment';
environment.url;
```

You can command:

```
ng serve --dev     // Or 
ng serve --prod
```

> Note: you should have environments directory directly in app directory and both environment files should be there.

Comment: Problem is that if you include prod configs in your environment files, you still end up committing them to your vcs tool. That also means that your ci will deploy a --prod build where the values (api-keys, passwords, and other sensitive information) could be read from the .bundle.js files. They're difficult to find, but they're there in clear text... For prod, you'll have to pull in config via a separate git repo, or find a way to provide environment variables.

Comment: From angular 6 onward, .angular-cli.json file is renamed to .angular.json [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824548/missing-angular-cli-json-file-angular)

Answer (score 4):

Check out [envsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envsub) for an easy way to build your configuration file `src/environments/environment.ts` by substituting environment variables into a [handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com) template file `src/environments/environment.hbs` using a package called [envsub](https://www.npmjs.com/package/envsub).

Make sure to delete the `environments` key from `.angular-cli.json`.

As an example, the content of `src/environments/environment.hbs` could be something like:

```
export const environment = {
    production: ${ MYAPP_PRODUCTION }
};
```

To substitute `MYAPP_PRODUCTION` with `false` run the following from the terminal.

```
MYAPP_PRODUCTION=false envsub src/environments/environment.hbs src/environments/environment.ts
```

The resulting file `src/environments/environment.ts` will be

```
export const environment = {
    production: false
};
```

You can add an additional script to `package.json` to build your configuration file.

```
"scripts": {
    "config": "envsub src/environments/environment.hbs src/environments/environment.ts",
}
```

Build your configuration by running something like the following in your terminal:

```
MYVAR=test npm run config
```

Remember to exclude `src/environments/environment.ts` from version control. For git you can use a `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the environment.ts file exports, for example, a constant named environment, then first you import the constant (using the appropriate path):

```
import { environment } from '../environment';
```

Then in code you just use the constant:

```
let mything = environment.mything;
```

Answer (score -1):

### I was stumbling over the same obstacle when a coworker sent me [this link](https://angular.io/guide/build)

Basically you define your "secret" in environments/environment.ts and then import environments in the component you want to use it, and then use it as follows **(according to the Angular docs)**

#### 1. Set it in environments/environment.ts

```
export const environment = { 
production: false, 
secret: "123456789"     //  <-- your "secret" variable
};
```

#### 2. Import it into your component

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
```

#### 3. Use it.

```
mySecret = environment.secret
```