# Is it possible to get a data from system environment variable in run time using Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, environment-variables

Is it possible to get a data from system environmet variable  in run time using Angular. if yes how can we do this ?

ex: Let say i set a value in environemnt varable

[image]

> So is it possible to get in angular from system environment variable in run time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can we use environment variable in angular version >=2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44622058/how-can-we-use-environment-variable-in-angular-version-2)

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT environment file where can i get?

Comment: Where did you set `API_URL : http://localhost:8080/api`?, I mean which file?

Comment: @SangramBadi , if you check Steven Stark's comment , you will get to know how to use it.

Comment: @JavascriptLover-SKT check my updated question

Comment: @StevenStark please check my updated question

Comment: @SangramBadi Your question is missing some important details, such as what environment your code sits in; is this the browser? Is it an ElectronJS-based application?  Does your app have access to node?  Why do you need this env variable?

Comment: can't you use any server side back-end like node/java to get this system env variable?

Comment: @Daedalus this angular project created using angular cli. so my question is it possible ?

Comment: @AbhishekGautam here server side and ui are separate projects. So is it possible to do ?

Comment: with angular you cannot get this system env variables, but with any server side language you can get! :)

Comment: @AbhishekGautam ok, thak you

Comment: @SangramBadi That only answers 1 of the several questions I asked.

Comment: Is it an ElectronJS-based application?ans: NO,  Does your app have access to node? ans :NO, Why do you need this env variable?ans: let say in future my api url chnage and i don't want to rebuild my application. @Daedalus

Comment: @SangramBadi I stand by my duplicate flag. Using Environment variables in any project is common practice. This is done at build time. If you are asking about at run time, then the answer is no you can not, and if this is what you are asking then it is not clear in your question.

Comment: @StevenStark i changed my question. thank you

Comment: Angular runs on browser not on server, and browser doesn't have access to system variables

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is no.

Environment variables are not exposed to JavaScript, they are used during build time only.