# Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found when upgraded to Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6, npm-install, ng-upgrade, npm-update

I have upgrading my project from Angular 5 to Angular 6. When I try to run the application using npm start it is throwing a below error.

[image]

I know that there is already questions like this that has answers, but I tried the most of them and those didn't work for me.

Comment: what is your folder structure? where is your angular.json?

Comment: Don't have angular.json file.. and it was working fine in angular 5 without angular.json file

Comment: With Angular 6.0.0 the filename is changed from .angular-cli.json to angular.json.
see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43824548/missing-angular-cli-json-file-angular

Comment: Just renamed it but no luck. Now its not even executing.

Comment: After renaming, its thowing an error in angular.json file for "Project" ,"apps" and so on. I believe even structure would be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was migrating from Angular version 5 to version 6. It came to my notice that angular 5 was using  **.angular-cli.json** file whereas after migrate it to version 6 I found that that from Angular 6 version don't support  **.angular-cli.json** file. So to make my project work I have migrated the .angular-cli.json file to angular.json. I used below command for the same.

```
ng update @angular/cli --from=1.7.4 --to=6 --migrate-only
```

Then I followed below steps.

1. I have removed my node_modules package from my application.
2. Cleaned the cache using `npm cache clean`
3. Verified the cache using `npm cache verify`
4. Re-installed it using `npm install`

After doing above steps it worked for me.